# How to work with properties in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Name { set; get; }

    public List<SimpleViewModel> Parameters
    {
        set
        {
            NotDeletedParameters = value.Where(t => !t.Deleted).ToList();
            parameters = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return parameters;
        }
    }

    private List<SimpleViewModel> parameters;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Parameters = new List<SimpleViewModel>();
    }

    public List<SimpleViewModel> NotDeletedParameters{ set; get; }
}
```

There are 2 list of parameters in this class: `Parameters` and `NotDeletedParameters`.

How can I set `NotDeletedParameters = value.Where(t => !t.Deleted).ToList();`  when I set a `Parameters` property.

When I use this code, `NotDeletedParameters` still has 0 elements in list. Any ideas?

Comment: This looks okay, unless I'm missing something.  Are you sure `value.Where(t => !t.Deleted).ToList()` has items in it?

Comment: Yeah im sure that `value` not empty.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? What are you trying to assign to `Parameters`?

Comment: @KliverMax are you sure that `value.Where(t => !t.Deleted).ToList()` is not empty? `value` could be non-empty while `value.Where(t => !t.Deleted).ToList()` can be empty.

Comment: Side note: I would not give NotDeletedParameters public set access if it is entirely dependent on Parameters

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but note there are other issues with this implementation: for example, if you use the get-ter for Parameters and add items to the list directly, they will "slip through the backdoor" and not get added to NotDeletedParameters. (Actually, this might be your issue, depending on how you are filling the list.)

Comment: Please show us how you assign to `ViewModel.Parameters`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NotDeletedParameters list would be empty because you're setting a new List to Parameters property which might not have deleted parameters. When you edit the list items of Parameters to set deleted parameters, the NotDeletedParameters list won't be updated because it has it's own copy which was assigned during initialization of Parameters.

So, Instead return a filtered list of Parameters in NotDeletedParameter.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Name { set; get; }

    public List<SimpleViewModel> Parameters
    {
        set
        {
            parameters = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return parameters;
        }
    }

    private List<SimpleViewModel> parameters;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Parameters = new List<SimpleViewModel>();
    }

    public List<SimpleViewModel> NotDeletedParameters{ 
         get {
               return parameters .Where(t => !t.Deleted).ToList();
             }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably avoid this issue by making NotDeletedParameters a get-only property that creates its list on-the-fly:

```
public List<SimpleViewModel> NotDeletedParameters
{
    get
    {
        return Parameters.Where(t => !t.Deleted).ToList();
    }
}
```

(I would also recommend returning an IEnumerable instead of a List, and changing the return statement to Parameters.Where(t => !t.Deleted).ToList().AsReadOnly()